Count the SQL table if all of its corresponding statuses in the task_status table are set to 'Completed'
I'm learning SQL solving Codewars tasks. I don't understand how to count a column, where all corresponding status are set to the same value.
Here's the task:

A home maintenance company uses a database to keep track of tasks that need to be performed at various houses. The database has two tables: house_tasks and task_status. The house_tasks table contains a list of tasks scheduled for each house identified by a house_id. The task_status table tracks the progress of each task, including a description and its current status.

house_tasks:
task_id (int, primary key): A unique identifier for each task.
house_id (int): The identifier of the house for which the task is scheduled.
task_name (varchar): The name of the task to be performed.

task_status:
id (int, primary key): A unique identifier for each task status record.
task_id (int): The identifier of the task which this status relates to.
description (varchar): A brief description of the task status.
task_status (varchar): The current status of the task; it can be 'Completed', 'In Progress', or NULL if the status has not been set.


Write a SQL query that generates a report for each house. The report should include the following columns:

house_id: The identifier of the house.
total_tasks: The total number of tasks scheduled for the house.
completed_tasks: The number of tasks that have been completed. A task is considered completed if all of its corresponding statuses in the task_status table are set to 'Completed'.
incomplete_tasks: The number of tasks that are not completed. A task is considered incomplete if any of its statuses are not 'Completed' or if the task does not have any status record in the task_status table.
The result should be ordered by house_id in descending order.

For this sample data:
house_tasks:
| task_id | house_id | task_name |
+---------+----------+-----------+
| 1       | 1        | Paint     |
| 2       | 1        | Plumb     |
| 3       | 1        | Garden    |
| 4       | 2        | Electric  |
| 5       | 2        | Roof      |
| 6       | 3        | Cleanup   |
| 7       | 4        | Extra Work|

task_status:
| task_id | description | task_status |
+---------+-------------+-------------+
| 1       | Desc 1      | Completed   |
| 1       | Desc 2      | Completed   |
| 1       | Desc 3      | Completed   |
| 2       | Desc 4      | In Progress |
| 2       | Desc 5      | In Progress |
| 3       | Desc 6      | In Progress |
| 3       | Desc 7      | Completed   |
| 4       | Desc 8      | Completed   |
| 5       | Desc 9      | NULL        |
| 7       | Desc 10     | NULL        |
| 7       | Desc 11     | Completed   |

desired output is the following:
| house_id | total_tasks | completed_tasks | incomplete_tasks |
+----------+-------------+-----------------+------------------+
| 4        | 1           | 0               | 1                |
| 3        | 1           | 0               | 1                |
| 2        | 2           | 1               | 1                |
| 1        | 3           | 1               | 2                |

Here's my query, that doesn't count correctly completed tasks:
SELECT
    house_id, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT house_tasks.task_id) AS total_tasks,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN task_status.task_status = 'Completed' THEN house_tasks.task_id END) AS completed_tasks,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN task_status.task_status IS NULL OR task_status.task_status <> 'Completed' THEN house_tasks.task_id END) AS incomplete_tasks
FROM 
    house_tasks
LEFT JOIN 
    task_status ON house_tasks.task_id = task_status.task_id
GROUP BY 
    house_id 
ORDER BY 
    house_id DESC;
    

My query shows:
house_id    total_tasks completed_tasks incomplete_tasks
4           1           1                1
3           1           0                1
2           2           1                1
1           3           1                2 



Can you share some sample data and the result expected for it? Offhand, your query looks correct.

@Mureinik I’ve added what’s wrong…I don’t understand how to filter if all corresponding columns have the same value “Completed”

Please read [mre] as well as Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example, even for a very simple SQL query? (You should include the sample data that relates to your expected results)

It appears that a house can have two rows for the same task id. One row indicating that it's incomplete and one (presumably a later row) that shows that the task is complete. You currently count tasks that have ever been incomplete. This means that you count each task for each and every state it has ever been in; the task for house 4 has been incomplete and has been complete, and so is counted for both. If that's so, just use the logic of "incomplete = total - complete". But, as you haven't included sample data, I'm just making an educated guess. Which is why [mre] is crucial.

Echoing what @MatBailie said: your model allows millions of task_status records for each house_task.  If you want a single status for each house_task then eliminate the task_status table entirely and move its columns to house_task.  If you want a task_status history then you'll need to add a date field or some other mechanism to sequence the records, but your reporting SQL will have to change drastically to access only the 'most recent' status record.

I've changed the question...

What RDBMS are you using? (Please tag it)

The important line is

A task is considered incomplete if any of its statuses are not 'Completed' or if the task does not have any status record in the task_status table

You could count the distinct tasks that have any rows that are not Completed, and deduct them from the Total to get the Completed...
SELECT
    house_tasks.house_id, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT house_tasks.task_id) AS total_tasks,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN task_status.task_status = 'Completed' THEN NULL ELSE house_tasks.task_id END) AS incomplete_tasks
    COUNT(DISTINCT house_tasks.task_id)
    - 
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN task_status.task_status = 'Completed' THEN NULL ELSE house_tasks.task_id END) AS complete_tasks
FROM 
    house_tasks
LEFT JOIN 
    task_status
        ON house_tasks.task_id = task_status.task_id
GROUP BY 
    house_tasks.house_id 
ORDER BY 
    house_tasks.house_id DESC;

Or, you could pre-aggregate the task_status table.
SELECT
    h.house_id, 
    COUNT(*)                            AS total_tasks,
    SUM(           t.is_complete    )   AS complete_tasks,
    COUNT(*) 
    - 
    SUM(           t.is_complete    )   AS incomplete_tasks_1,
    SUM(1-COALESCE(t.is_complete, 0))   AS incomplete_tasks_2
FROM 
    house_tasks   AS h
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    task_id,
    MIN(CASE WHEN task_status = 'Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS is_complete
  FROM
    task_status
  GROUP BY
    task_id
)
  AS t
    ON h.task_id = t.task_id
GROUP BY 
    h.house_id 
ORDER BY 
    h.house_id DESC;

The COALESCE is required to ensure that tasks without any statuses are treated as incomplete.

Pre-aggregation (2nd option) is probably more efficient as SQL Server doesn't deal well with COUNT(DISTINCT CASE...
